# Whitehead theorem for maps between CW-complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes, higher-homotopy-groups

I was wondering : if $f,g : X \rightarrow Y$ are continuous maps between CW-complexes, if they induce the same morphisms on homotopy groups, does that imply that $f$ and $g$ are homotopic? It would seem plausible, similar to a Whitehead theorem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not true.

Take $S^n\times S^n$ and consider the quotient map

$$q_n:S^n\times S^n\rightarrow S^n\wedge S^n\cong S^{2n}$$

where $S^n\wedge S^n=S^n\times S^n/S^n\vee S^n$ is the smash product. Then $q_n$ induces the trivial morphism on homotopy groups in all dimensions, since if $\alpha:S^r\rightarrow S^n\times S^n$ is any map, then by naturality $q_{n*}\alpha$ factors as

$q\circ\alpha:S^r\xrightarrow\Delta S^r\times S^r\xrightarrow{q_{r*}}S^r\wedge S^r\cong S^{2r}\rightarrow S^{2n} $

which is trivial since $\pi_rS^{2r}=0$.

On the other hand $q_n\not\simeq\ast$, since in homology the induced map

$$q_{n*}:H_{2n}(S^n\times S^n)\xrightarrow{}H_{2n}(S^n\wedge S^n)$$

is an isomorphism.

Comment: I am surprised there is such a simple example. Thanks !

Comment: I am feeling slow.  In your second displayed equation, what is the map $S^r \wedge S^r\rightarrow S^{2n}$?

Comment: @Ludovic: My favorite example is the map $T^3\rightarrow S^2$ from the three torus to 2-sphere, given by the composition $T^3\rightarrow S^3\rightarrow S^2$, where the first map collapses the 2-skeleton to a point and the second map is the Hopf map.  It is trivial on all homotopy groups and (co)homology groups (for trivial reasons).  However, it is not homotopically trivial,  because the Hopf map is a fibration.  If it was trivial, then the collapsing map is trivial, but it's not because it's nontrivial on $H^3$.  Also, to give proper credit, this in an excercise in Hatcher's AT book.

Comment: @JasonDeVito  $S^r \rightarrow S^n \times S^n$ determines two maps $f,g : S^r \rightarrow S^n$, then $S^r \wedge S^r \rightarrow S^{2n}$ is induced by $S^r \times S^r \rightarrow S^n \times S^n$ which is $(f,g)$. Hope that's clear.
Thanks for the second example !

Comment: @Ludovic:. I am sorry, but I'm still being slow.  What is the map $S^r\times S^r\rightarrow S^n\times S^n$?  Giving a map out of a product is more complicated than just giving maps on each factor.  What am I missing?

Comment: @JasonDeVito The two components $pr_1f,pr_2f$ of the map $f:S^r\rightarrow S^n\times S^n$ determine it completely. That is, $f$ is just the composite $S^r\xrightarrow{\Delta}S^r\times S^r\xrightarrow{pr_1f\times pr_2f}S^n\times S^n$. Then $q_nf=q_n(pr_1f\times pr_2f)\Delta_r=(pr_1f)\wedge (pr_2f)q_r\Delta_r$, and $q_r\Delta_r$ is null-homotopic. Try drawing a diagram to see what is going on.

Comment: @JasonDeVito, note that example $T^3=S^1\times S^1\times S^1\rightarrow S^3\xrightarrow{\eta} S^2$ is a special case of what I am considering, since the first map is exactly the pinch map that I am using (it factors $S^1\times S^1\times S^1\xrightarrow{q_1\times 1} (S^1\wedge S^1)\times S^1\rightarrow S^1\wedge S^1\wedge S^1=S^3$)

Comment: @LudovicMonier if you are interested in the idea and seeing more ideas and examples, then there is a nice paper by M. Arkowtiz, K. Maruyama and D. Stanley, *The Semigroup of Self-Homotopy Classes Which Induce Zero on Homotopy Groups*.

Comment: @Tyrone: Ah, I was missing the extra projections needed to go from a map $S^r\rightarrow S^n\times S^n$ to a map $S^r\times S^r\rightarrow S^n\times S^n$.  Now I see why the map factors.  Thanks for putting up with me!

Comment: @Tyrone I will check this reference, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

In the case that your domain is a suspension or your codomain is a loop space, one may add and subtract maps. In this setting, this means there is an equivalence between your question and the question “Are null homotopic maps the same as maps inducing trivial maps on homotopy groups?”

It tends to be the case in homological algebra as well as homotopy theory that we can phrase similar statements about isomorphisms and zero maps. Your’s is about transferring Whitehead from isomorphisms to zero maps. And there are similar versions of Whitehead in the case of homological algebra.

But these analogous results tend to not to be true in either case