# Homotopy classes and Induced map being injective

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I've been solving the exercise 3 of Chapter 15 Section 2 in Topology written by James Dugundji.

The exercise question is:

> Let $\phi:X \rightarrow Y$ be continuous. Prove $\phi^{*} :[Y,Z] \rightarrow [X,Z]$ is injective for every Z iff there is a continuous $\rho:Y \rightarrow X$ such that $\phi \circ \rho \simeq 1_Y.$

The $\phi^{*}$ is defined as $\phi^{*}[f] = [f \circ \phi]$ where $[f]$ denotes the homotopy class of $f$.

I proved a similar exercise but with surjectivity and the $\Leftarrow$ by using that $f \circ \phi \simeq g \circ \phi$ whenever $f \simeq g$. However, with the $\Rightarrow$, my friends and I have been stuck for several hours not even coming up with any results. Seems like this is supposed to be a routine but we found this quite challenging.

So my question is:

1. Is $(\Rightarrow)$ right?
2. Any hints or counterexamples regarding this exercise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement is quite false as it stands.

For my example I'll need some facts not contained in Dugundji's book. Unfortunately, I know of no simpler construction. Hatcher's book and Arkowitz's book are good references for what follows.

> **Fact:** If $\phi:X\rightarrow Y$ is a basepoint-preserving map between connected CW complexes and for some path-connected pointed space $Z$ the induced map $\phi^*:[Y,Z]_\ast\rightarrow[X,Z]_\ast$ of pointed homotopy sets is injective, then the induced map $\phi^*:[Y,Z]\rightarrow[X,Z]$ of unpointed homotopy sets is also injective.

Note that the converse fails. In any case, if $X$ is a connected CW complex and $Z$ any space, then two maps $f,g:X\rightarrow Z$ can be homotopic only if $f(X)$ and $g(X)$ are contained in the same path-component $Z_0$ of $Z$. In this case, $f\simeq g$ if and only if the two restrictions $f',g':X\rightarrow Z_0$ are homotopic.

Thus if we take $X=S^n\times S^n$ and $Y=S^{2n}$, and let
$$\phi:S^n\times S^n\rightarrow S^{2n}$$
be the map pinching to the top cell, then in the sequel it will be sufficient to work with path-connected pointed spaces and assume all maps and homotopies preserve basepoints. I'll continue to use $[-,-]_*$ to denote *pointed* homotopy classes of *pointed* maps.

Now, we have a cofiber sequence.

$$S^{2n-1}\xrightarrow{\omega} S^n\vee S^n\xrightarrow{i}S^n\times S^n\xrightarrow\phi S^{2n}$$
where $i$ is the inclusion of the $(2n-1)$-skeleton and $\omega$ is the Whithead product. The sequence extends to the right in the standard manner, with the next map being the suspension $\Sigma\omega:S^{2n}\rightarrow\Sigma(S^n\vee S^n)\cong S^{n+1}\vee S^{n+1}$. However,
$$\Sigma (S^n\times S^n)\simeq S^{n+1}\vee S^{n+1}\vee S^{2n+1},$$
and the map $\Sigma i:\Sigma(S^n\vee S^n)\rightarrow \Sigma(S^n\times S^n)$ has a right homotopy inverse $\alpha$. Consequently

$$\Sigma\omega\simeq(\alpha\circ\Sigma i)\circ\omega\simeq\alpha\circ(\Sigma i\circ\Sigma\omega)\simeq\alpha\circ\Sigma(i\circ\omega)\simeq\alpha\circ\ast\simeq\ast$$
since $i,\omega$ are adjancent maps in a cofiber sequence.

On the other hand, the segment
$$S^n\times S^n\xrightarrow\phi S^{2n}\xrightarrow{\Sigma\omega}S^{n+1}\vee S^{n+1}$$
is a cofiber sequence, so if $Z$ is any space and $f:S^{2n}\rightarrow Z$ a map with $\phi^*(f)=f\circ\phi\simeq\ast$, then there is $g:S^{n+1}\vee S^{n+1}\rightarrow Z$ such that $f\simeq g\circ\Sigma\omega$. Of course $\Sigma\omega$ being trivial forces $f\simeq\ast$.

> **Proposition:** $\phi^*:[S^{2n},Z]_*\rightarrow[S^n\times S^n,Z]_*$ is injective for any space $Z$. $\quad\blacksquare$

On the other hand, the map $\phi:S^n\times S^n\rightarrow S^{2n}$ [induces the trivial map on all homotopy groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3318476/whitehead-theorem-for-maps-between-cw-complexes/3318522#3318522). Thus if $\rho:S^{2n}\rightarrow S^n\times S^n$ is *any map*, then $\phi\circ\rho\simeq\ast$.

> **Proposition:** $\phi$ has no right homotopy inverse. $\quad\blacksquare$

Comment: I beat my head on this problem for quite some time.  I glad that it seems the answer is difficult, using homotopy theory I don't know!

Comment: @JasonDeVito it's very possible that there is a much more elementary counterexample.  On the other hand, the approach here has the upside that it shows that the problem isn't a feature of pathological spaces. If you have any suggestions for how I could improve the exposition above through better explanation, I'd very much welcome your comments!

Comment: There may be a more elementary example, but how could you prove that $\phi^\ast$ is injective for all $Z$ without some homotopy theory?  As far as suggestions, I need to read it much more carefully (I'll have time for that in approximately an hour), but on the outside, I'm confused as to how your second-to-last proposition is helpful in light of your comment that the Converse of the Fact fails.

Comment: @JasonDeVito I think that was just a problem with my notation, which is now slightly improved!

Comment: Ok, I've gone through it more carefully.  1.  I don't understand the Fact.  Should the last $[X,Z]$ be $[Z,Y]$?  Actually, I don't see where you use the Fact at all.  2.  In the displayed formula beginning with $\Sigma w$, I think the next term should be $(\alpha \circ \Sigma i)\circ \Sigma w)$ instead of $\Sigma(\alpha \circ\Sigma  i) \circ w$.  3.  What this part of the argument seems to establish is that $\phi^\ast[S^{2n}, Z]_\ast \rightarrow [S^n\times S^n]_\ast$ is injective (note that $Z$s come last in my formulation).  This is exactly what's needed to be a counterexample.   (continued).

Comment: 4.  The proof that $\Sigma w$ is trivial, it seems to assume that $\Sigma w$ is trivial when asserting that $\Sigma S^n\times S^n\cong S^{n+1}\vee S^{n+1}\vee S^{2n+1}$, for otherwise there could be an interesting attaching map $\partial D^{2n+1}\rightarrow S^{n+1}\vee S^{n+1}.$

Comment: $1.$ Yes. I presume Op is interested in unpointed homotopy (which is what Dugundji covers) and the fact shows why the pointed analysis that follows is relevant. $2.$ Yes. $3.$ This is what I was trying to claim. $4.$ There are many way to show that Whitehead products suspend trivially and you can replace my ramblings with your favourite. My preferred method is to take the projections $\pi_1,\pi_2:S^n\times S^n\rightarrow S^n$, suspend them, and use the suspension coordinate to add them to produce a map $\Sigma(S^n\times S^n)\rightarrow S^{n+1}\vee S^{n+1}$ which is right inverse to $\Sigma i$.

Comment: Oh! I was thinking that the focus of the Fact was telling you something about maps *from* $Z$ into $X$ and $Y$ given knowledge about $[Y,Z]_\ast$ and $[X,Z]_\ast$, not about based vs unbased.  Now I understand!  Regarding 4, I wasn't trying to cast aspersions on the claimed result, just trying to make sure I understood the proof.  (I'm a homotopy theory novice).  I'll try to work through the details of your last comment once I have time.  Thanks for putting up with me!